# Problems with sending back to back emails with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, smtp

We are having problems with sending back to back emails on one of our web sites. The site is built with .net framework 2.0.

We can send the first email without any problems on every try. But to send a second email you need to wait about 20-30 minutes.

Below is our code if it would help diagnose the problem.

One thing we tried was changing the smtp email server. We tried a third party smtp server but the same problem persisted. So I think the problem is not with the smtp server but with our .net code.

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Mail

Namespace websiteCode
    Public Class mailer
        Const mailTo As String = "receiver@test.com"
        Const mailFrom As String = "sender@test.com"
        Const smtpServer As String = "192.168.1.1"
        Const username As String = "user"
        Const password As String = "password"



        Public Function send(ByVal emailaddress As String, ByVal messagebody As String, ByVal subject As String) As Boolean
            'If checkdata(emailaddress, messagebody) Then
            Using mm As New MailMessage(mailFrom, mailTo)
                mm.To.Add(New MailAddress("receıver@test.com"))
                mm.Subject = subject
                mm.Body = messagebody
                mm.IsBodyHtml = True
                mm.ReplyTo = New MailAddress(emailaddress)
                Dim smtp As New SmtpClient
                smtp.Host = smtpServer
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = False
                smtp.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(username, password)



                Try
                    smtp.Send(mm)
                    Return True
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Return False
                End Try

            End Using
            Return True
        End Function




    End Class
End Namespace
```

**UPDATE-1: SOLUTION**

```
<%@ OutputCache CacheProfile="static" %>
```

Removing the above code from the .aspx file resolved the problem. Now I can send back to back emails without any issues.
I've googled around to see if anyone explained how this directive conflicts with email sending but so far I have no clue.
Anyways, the problem is solved.

<%@ OutputCache CacheProfile="static" %>

Comment: It was broken before because asp.net things the page that calls into this code was just rendering html. Subsequent hits to page would be filled by the cache and your code would never run.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the reason of your bug, but you should definitely dispose of the SmtpClient object once you're done. From documentation:

> The SmtpClient class has no Finalize
>   method, so an application must call
>   Dispose to explicitly free up
>   resources. The Dispose method iterates
>   through all established connections to
>   the SMTP server specified in the Host
>   property and sends a QUIT message
>   followed by gracefully ending the TCP
>   connection. The Dispose method also
>   releases the unmanaged resources used
>   by the Socket and optionally disposes
>   of the managed resources.

**EDIT:** For .NET framework < 4.0 there is no dispose method actually. You can try the workaround method suggested [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/337557/smtpclient-does-not-close-session-after-sending-message). Another suggested workaround [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/146711/smtp-never-sends-the-quit-command). Hope this helps.

Comment: My understanding was that it is not possible to dispose the SmtpClient object within Framework v2.0. Were you referring to v4.0? I've added mm.Dispose() after your answer to my code and tried again. No luck. It is interesting, whenever I submit new vb code to the ftp, the very first time I try emailing it works. I think you are on point about something not being disposed. But I'm not sure what.

Comment: You're right, I just noticed this also. Look at my edit for links to workarounds that you could try.